# Daemon creation not working using Win32Utils ruby gem

Tags: ruby, winapi, windows-services

This is the code I am trying to run as a service.

```
            require 'rubygems'
            require 'win32/daemon'
            require 'win32/service'
            include Win32

               class Daemon
                  def service_main
                 while running?
                    sleep 3
                    File.open("c:\\test.log", "a"){ |f| f.puts "service is running" }
                 end
                  end

                  def service_stop
                 exit!
                  end
               end

            Daemon.mainloop
```

This is the code I use to register the Service
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'win32/service'

```
include Win32

SERVICE_NAME = 'ruby_sample1'

# Create a new service
ser = Service.create({
  :service_name        => SERVICE_NAME,
  :service_type       => Service::WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
  :description        => 'A custom service I wrote just for fun',
  :start_type         => Service::AUTO_START,
  :error_control      => Service::ERROR_NORMAL,
  :binary_path_name   => 'c:\\Ruby186\\bin\\ruby.exe -C c:\\temp\\test.rb',
  :load_order_group   => 'Network',
  :dependencies       => ['W32Time','Schedule'],
  :display_name       => SERVICE_NAME
})
```

After the service is registered I try to start the service from services.msc. I get an error that says "Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"

Answer (score 2):

open an irb session and say - require 'win32/daemon'

Most likely you'll get the answer to 1053 problem especially if you have installed win32-service gem for platform mswin32.

I had the same problem and win32-service gem just won't build for platform ruby on my machine even after installing devkit. It persistently gave me following error

win32/daemon.c:141:7: error: '__try' undeclared (first use in this function)

Eventually I ended by building win32-service gem from the latest code on github.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me, +1. Appears to be fixed in 0.7.2 but if you can't wait, do 'git clone <https://github.com/djberg96/win32-service.git>' Then in resulting directory do 'gem build win32-service.gemspec' Then 'gem install --local win32-service-0.7.2.gem' Be sure to gem uninstall the mswin32 version as it will always error against RubyInstaller build.